# How can I order by number if parts of string?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Is there a way to order by a decimal part of a string? My data is stored something like this: `Some string value xx.yy`, where `xx.yy` is a decimal number.

```
SELECT some_string FROM table ORDER BY some_string desc;
```

Results in the following:

```
Some string value 18.9
Some string value 18.8
Some string value 18.7
...
Some string value 18.2
Some string value 18.13
Some string value 18.12
Some string value 18.11
Some string value 18.10
Some string value 18.1
```

But the desired result is the following:

```
Some string value 18.13
Some string value 18.12
Some string value 18.11
Some string value 18.10
Some string value 18.9
Some string value 18.8
Some string value 18.7
...
Some string value 18.1
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to play with the functions.

> Please refer to https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

`SUBSTR`, `LENGTH`, `INSTR` are main ones who can save you. You will get to know once you will start exploring them.

or

**Still I prefer to separate and store both the values into individual columns. This will provide you more flexibility when it comes to data manipulation.**

Comment: Yes, optimally this would be two columns, but this is a legacy system without much flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

If the prefix is the same length, you can use this trick:

```
order by len(some_string) desc, some_string_desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick. `len` is apparently not a SQLite function. Thanks, @gordon-linoff.

```
SELECT some_string 
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY length(some_string) desc, some_string desc
```